# I can't add column of type geography in oracle 11 g

Tags: oracle

I want to add a column of type geography in  oracle 11 g when I create the table and add a column I can found the data type geography

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1LUF.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's `SDO_GEOMETRY` data type you're looking for, I presume.

```
SQL> create table test (id number,
  2                     geo sdo_geometry);

Table created.

SQL>
```

More about it in [Spatial Data types and Metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_objrelschema.htm#SPATL020).